# Form Validation "Custom Required"

Tags: javascript, html

**How to fix this code ?**

```js
function shw() {
   document.getElementById('done').style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<form name="validation" action="">
<p>what is the capital of England ?</p>
<p>A.London<br>B.Manchester</p>
<input type="text" id="answer" required> 
<button type="submit" value="submit" onclick="shw()">Submit</button>
<!-- If Asnwer is true -->
<!-- All content in form is HIDDEN (Text,input and button), then, show this -->
<div id="done"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" >Answer Is True</div>

<!-- If Asnwer is wrong/ -->
<!-- All content in form NOT HIDDEN, then, show this in bottom form -->
<div id="done"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" >Answer Is Wrong</div>
</form>
```

Example Image : http://www112.zippyshare.com/v/CKwyAAiM/file.html (True Answer)
Example Image : http://www112.zippyshare.com/v/Lx7TvOwp/file.html (Wrong Answer)
**Note :**
*-Must Write **London** on Input, to continue
A.if answer is true, text, input and button on form is hidden then show complete text
B.if answer is wrong, text, input and button NOT HIDDEN, show text "wrong Answer" in bottom form*

Comment: You can write your algorithm to determine the correct answer in your javascript. But it wont be secure (anyone who opens up the console will see which answer is correct), u will need to use some backend  tool to make it secure and secret

Comment: hehehe... I can secure. But compiling it as I wanted it, it made my head burn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below sample code will do the validation. Note that all the checking and the questions are hard coded based on the example you provided. As JapanGuy indicated in comments, you need to use some secure way of checking for answers.

```
<form name="validation" action="" id="formName">
    <div id="question">
        <p>what is the capital of England ?</p>
        <p>A.London<br>B.Manchester</p>
        <input type="text" id="answer" required> 
        <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>    

    <!-- If Asnwer is true -->
    <!-- All content in form is HIDDEN (Text,input and button), then, show this -->
    <div id="correct"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" >Answer Is True</div>

    <!-- If Asnwer is true */ -->
    <!-- All content in form NOT HIDDEN, then, show this in bottom form -->
    <div id="wrong"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" >Answer Is Wrong</div>
</form>

<script>
    var form = document.getElementById("formName");
    form.addEventListener("submit", shw, true);

    function shw(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (document.getElementById("answer").value == "London")
        {
            document.getElementById("question").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('correct').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('wrong').style.display = "none";
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('correct').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('wrong').style.display = "block";
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Waw....nice code, Mr.Kumar. 
Youre Help me, fix this problem... Thank you.

Perfect...
i can try to Encrypt the Script to hide the true answer, Is that good?

Comment: It should be good. It all depends on the backend database and the logic you write for encrypt/decrypt.